# time-sensitive documents, goods, articles or cargo

Tags: nouns, adjectives

> time-sensitive documents, goods, articles or cargo

In the phrase reproduced above, does it mean that only documents are time-sensitive or does time-sensitive apply to goods, articles and cargo as well?

Answer (score 2):

The ambiguity there is perfect. To clear it up, one should revise it to either

> such documents, goods, articles[,] and cargoes as are time-sensitive

(if the time-sensitivity is shared by all), or

> goods, articles, cargoes[,] and time-sensitive documents

(if only the documents are time-sensitive).

(The bracketed commas are so-called [Oxford or serial commas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).)

Comment: Agreed. The most likely solution is that 'time-sensitive' applies to all the items.  Hwever, without further context it is impossible to be certain.

Comment: Here is the whole paragraph (context):-

Courier services mean the transmission, transportation or conveyance, whether door-to-door or not of time-sensitive documents, goods, articles or cargo whether or not utilizing the services of a person either directly or indirectly to accompany such documents, goods, articles or cargo.

Comment: I would take that to mean that "time-sensitive" applies to all, especially since the same items are mentioned as a group without the modifier later in the sentence. But it is a little ambiguous from a grammatical standpoint.